# Can't store data with Axios

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I was trying to store form data with Vue using Axios.

Here is the vue template:

```
  <template id="AddEmployee">
    <div>
     <h3> Add new post</h3>
     <form v-on:submit.prevent="createEmployee">
       <div class="form-group">
         <label> name</label>
         <input type="text"  v-model="employee.name" class="form-control" required placeholder="">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label> Email</label>
         <input type="email"  v-model="employee.email" class="form-control" required placeholder="">
       </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"> Create </button>
       <router-link class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" v-bind:to="'/crud/public/'"> Cancel</router-link>
     </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      data:function()
      {
        return {employee: { name:'', email:''}}
      },
      methods:{
        createEmployee:function()
        {
          let uri = 'http://localhost/crud/public/employees';
           Axios.post(uri, this.employee).then((response)=>{
            this.$router.push({name: 'Employees'})
           })
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::resource('/employees','EmployeeController');
```

Here is the controller part:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
      'name' => 'required',
      'email' => 'required',
    ]);

    $create = Employee::create($request->all());
    return response()->json(['status' => 'success','msg'=>'Employee created successfully']);
}
```

Here is the routes defined in app.js

```
const routes = [
    {
        name : 'Employees',
        path: '/crud/public/',
        component : Employees
    },
    {
        name : 'AddEmployee',
        path: '/crud/public/AddEmployee',
        component : AddEmployee
    }
   ]
```

But the problem is it redirects me to Employees route but nothing stored in database.

Comment: try changing your route to an apiResouce  `Route::apiResource('employees', 'EmployeeController');`

Comment: What does the inspect tool in your browser show when you look at the AJAX request?

Comment: your axios post, replace your 'uri' with just '\employees' `Axios.post('\employees', this.employee).then((response)=>{
            this.$router.push({name: 'Employees'})'`

Comment: That throws me `Object not found!` Error as it redirects to `http://localhost/employees 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: @User57 my bad. try forward slash '/employees'

Comment: I tried with that also it redirects to `http://localhost/employees`

Comment: Any js errors in the browser console? also, afaik `axios` should be lower cased.

Comment: No Error in console. while submitting the form . the value not stored but it redirected to respective page.

Comment: `console.log` the promise's response from `Axios.post` and see if you get your `status = 'success'` in in. My guess is the error is on the server side, like something is up with the data that you try to insert in the model.